# React Part of State is Empty Inside Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I have a react / Redux app. The problem is that I want to render an list of elements in my component's state and this list is always empty when the render method is executed and I can't use it.

This elements come from an API call.

This is my component:

```
class PeopleView extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    people: PropTypes.array,
    view: PropTypes.string
  }

  static stateToProps = state => ({
    people: state.properties.items || [],
    sortedPeople: sortBy(state.people.items || [], 'birthday'),
  })

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { people } = props;
    const sortedPeople = sortBy(people, 'birthday');

    this.state = {
      people: people,
      sortedPeople: sortedPeople,
      collapsed: true
    };
  }    

  toggleCollapsed = (e) => {
    this.setState({collapsed: !this.state.collapsed});
  }

  deleteHandler = (id) => {
    console.log("Person Id", id)    
  }

  render() {

    // THIS IS EMPTY: this.state.people = [] 
    // THIS IS NOT EMPTY: this.props.people = [{...}, {...}, {...}, ...]

    const sortedPeople = sortBy(this.props.people, 'createdAt');
    const sortedPeopleElements = this.props.sortedPeople.map((p, i) => {
      return <li key={p.id}>
        <Person index={i} id={p.id} name={p.name} onDelete={this.deleteHandler} />              
      </li>
    });    

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
         {sortedPeopleElements}                  
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(PeopleView);
```

The people lis in the state is always empty in the render method, but the people list in props is always fine. Why is this?

How can I set up the state to work with render and start deleting people from this list?

Comment: missing parameters in `connect()`

Comment: @xadm I get this `Uncaught ReferenceError: stateToProps is not defined` when changing it to this: connect(stateToProps)(PeopleView);

Comment: Because you will have to create method `stateToProps`.

Comment: why defined as static? move it out of component body

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in general in your code.

1. `this.state.people` is only initialized in the constructor once from the value of `this.props.people` which by default is `undefined` if you didn't pass in an value. Note that you didn't use `this.state.people` anywhere in your `render` method.
2. You're mixing up React's component state and Redux's state.  Redux's state is pass to React as props (typically via a mapping function called mapStateToProps, you can call it anything you want). This mapping function needs to be pass to connect(mapStateToProps)(PeopleView). react-redux's connect function is a curry function.
3. By convention, you really don't need to make the `stateToProps` a static method of the component class. Usually, it's top level (or file scope) for that function.

Let me know if I can further clarify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

/* Remove { } this brackets from the const variable and also you need props.people not props in it */
    const people  = props.people; 
    const sortedPeople = sortBy(people, 'birthday');

    this.state = {
      people: people,
      sortedPeople: sortedPeople,
      collapsed: true
    };
  }
```